Perforated sump well or solid in 1851 Home's cellar?
Here's my situation:
The House is located in Central New York, in farm country.
The cellar floor is concrete slab, walls are original rocks (yes, rocks) from the original 1851 foundation.The rocks have been filled with mortar/cement, but in times of excess surface moisture, water comes through the rocks and through the slab. Cellar is mostly below grade (~7 ft below grade). Exterior surface is graded to slope away from house.
Winter and early spring are the worst times. Up to 2 inches of water will accumulate in the basement's lowest point. The existing sump well/pump is .. well, I'd say a "home owner special" but that would be insulting to home owners!
Some previous owner cut a rough pit in the slab at the cellar's lowest point, and dropped a 5-gallon HD bucket with the top ribbed section sticking about the slab grade. There's no fill or cement between the bucket and the rough-cut well opening in the slab/ground.
When water infiltrates the cellar, water flows to the corner of the basement where the existing sump well is located. The sump pump works fine, but inefficiently -- trips way too often when there's water in the basement, and that bucket lip sticking above the slab literally acts as a damn forcing water to accumulate before being pumped out. Someone at one time punched a couple holes in the bucket, but they are far fewer than on a commercial sump well liner.
There are no drainage tiles/pipes anywhere in the basement, and considering various factors, installing drain tiles/lines is not an option.
It's summer as I write this and there's only been one incident in months of any water in the basement (that was after exceptionally strong storms left over from Hurricane Debby).
ISSUE: Obviously, a 5-gallon bucket isn't a proper sump well. I'm looking to replace that 5-gallon HD bucket with a proper sump well, but considering the messed up existing installation, I want to be sure any work I perform isn't a gigantic waste of money and is done properly. {I'm a "Fix once -- the right way" kinda guy.]
CONSIDERATIONS:

Perforated or solid sump well?
Size? [Example" HD lists two different sizes 17" x 16" and 18" x 22").
Suggested sump pump size/HP considerations? Water has to lift ~9 ft vertically, then goes through an exterior line ~20 ft.
Power company-provided electricity cuts off regularly throughout the year.Is battery backup worth the additional cost/maintenance?

Any assistance/recommendations you can give me are greatly appreciated.

Regardless of the reliability of power, a backup pump is a good thing to have. Float switches stick, pumps die, ... . A second pump and switch located above the main pump's level will take over if anything fails or the pump can't keep up. I splurged on a Water Witch bilge switch so that I wouldn't have to worry about mechanical issues with a switch that is rarely used. A 500GPH 12VDC bilge pump set up on bricks in the sump, battery and smart charger complete the set. 2" of rain in 30min and no power for 2.5 days last week. No problem.

Thanks for the advice. I'll look into this further; sounds reasonable. Much appreciated.

Seems like the main problem with the bucket, is it sticks up too much.
If it works, it works.
Cutting the top off level with the slab seems like a good solution.
Perforated sump pits want gravel/fine mesh to keep dirt out and are good if the water comes from below the floor. From the walls only, it won't matter much if perforated or not.
9ft up should be in specs for even the smallest(1/3hp) power sump pumps.
Battery and/or a generator is nice when the power is out and the water keeps coming in.  There are a couple of other types that do not depend on on power.  Not sure of the name, but maybe water ram pumps/non-electric sump pumps.

Thank you for the advice. Much appreciated. A fair amount of the water infiltration comes from under the slab (on place on the floor looks like a small fountain when rains are exceptionally heavy). I'm leaning on putting in a larger perforated sump well because of the 50:50 infiltration sources, but haven't made up my mine yet.
As for the current hookup, it works -- kinda/sorta/maybe/when it wants to. Pump works extra hard, switching on and off every 5 -8 minutes. That seems to frequent to me, but it's been decades since I've had a sump pump.

Sump pumps are off with no water all the way up to on constantly and cannot keep up.  It all depends how fast the water comes in.  A bigger pit does help in those cases.
